# Quel est le sens de « médiatiser » dans ce contexte ?

Tags: sens, verbes, littérature

Dans le livre *Histoire de la littérature française* de Xavier Darcos j'ai lu ce fragment faisant référence à Corneille (j'y ai ajouté les caractères en gras):

> Malgré ces variations, le héros, pour être admirable, doit rester tendu vers des idéaux. Surmontant le simple amour né du coup de foudre ou du désir, il est en quête d'une énergie qui puisse donner une impulsion à sa vie. Cette tension est une forme de l'orgueil, de l'appétit de « gloire ». Elle peut se réaliser dans la foi, dans l'honneur, dans le patriotisme, dans l'ambition. Elle est évidemment contrecarrée par l'amour – d'où de fréquents heurts entre ce qu'on doit et ce qu'on aime. Le conflit cornélien repose sur cet antagonisme apparent, prétexte à **médiatiser**,
> auprès de tout spectateur, la sympathie et l'identification immédiates. Mais, bien entendu, les enjeux sont plus complexes.

J'ai cherché le verbe « médiatiser » dans des
dictionnaires ([1](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/mediatiser) et [2](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/m%C3%A9diatiser)), mais je n'en comprends pas le sens  dans le contexte de l'extrait ci-dessus. Faire de la sympathie et de l'identification immédiates un intermédiaire avec le spectateur ? Quelqu'un pourrait-il m'expliquer ce que cela veut dire ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Médiatiser n'a pas ici son sens courant actuel, faire connaître par l'intermédiaire des médias (TV, radio, journaux, etc.), mais le sens plus ancien d'insérer un intermédiaire entre deux choses, les rendre « médiates », c'est à dire non-immédiates, indirectes.

Ici, le conflit cornélien s'interpose d'une certaine manière entre le spectateur et le héros, fait prendre au spectateur un certain recul rendant plus complexe la sympathie et l'identification qu'il aurait sinon eu plus facilement avec ce dernier.